# Mysql-php how to implement connection pool with php v 5.2 and no persistent connection allowed

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to implement connection pooling in with php v5.2.17 , so singleton is not present for this version. Also apparently persistent connections not allowed by my webhost as `php phpinfo()` shows:

> Directive..................................Local
>   Value........................Master Value
>   mysql.allow_persistent........................Off....................................Off

If no connection pool is possible then can there be any workaround? use some other language etc. It is a must for me to reduce number of mysql connections.

Also the query to the database by the users is exactly the same query i.e. it is not dependent upon the user or the session. Its a hardcoded songle query. Just incase this info might help. 
thanks.

Comment: off topic, but please be aware that PHP 5.2 is badly out of date -- it was declared end of life more than two years ago, and has had no support at all since then. PHP 5.3 has been available since 2009, so your web host is a long way off the curve. You should ask them why they haven't upgraded, since there are known security issues with 5.2 that aren't going to be fixed.

Comment: As for persistent connections, it's fairly common for a shared hosting provider to disable it (regardless of language), as a badly written program using it could affect other users on the same box. If you need it, you could try asking them about it, but my guess is that you'll need to upgrade to a VM hosting to get that kind of feature. (in any case, if you're worried about performance and scalability, which is implied by wanting persistent connections, then you're probably outgrowing a shared hosting environment anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments @SDC gives, just wanted to mak this "formal".

Given all that, I'm afraid you're probably out of luck. You have no way in that version of PHP to create persistent connections. Your only option was mysql_pconnect, which obviously have been disabled by the host.

You're down to the three options @SDC suggests:

- Get them to allow it/upgrade PHP.
- Switch to a host which is more permissive.
- Self-hosting